# Advance Function InStr

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I know how to use the function InStr, but what I don't know is how to use it this way:

[Image of my excel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jb6XN.png)
I want to make a loop to insert the data in the right cells.
My code to add the 2nd element is:

```
For j = 3 To 129
    For i = 2 To 849
        Cells(i, j) = Mid(Cells(i, 1), InStr(Cells(i, 1), ",") + 1, (InStr(InStr(Cells(i, 1), ",") + 1, Cells(i, 1), ",")) - (InStr(Cells(i, 1), ",") + 1))
    Next i
Next j
```

The problem is, I would have to use a complicated loop to do a lot of InStr depending on the variable j.

If the function InStr had a place where I say: I wanna find the **x**th character (",") I would make it work; the problem is that I need a double InStr to ignore the 1st "," so it gives me the position of the 2nd ",".

I think the question is a lot more complicated, so ask me anything you didn't understand!

P.S.: I already inserted the values of the column B/entry and C/class.

Comment: You know that InStr allows you to specify where it starts looking from, so if you tell it to begin from position 4 in your string, it will ignore the initial 3 chars.  This would skip the first comma in the example data you provided: `Instr(4,Cells(i,1), ",")+1`

Comment: I know, the problem is that the way I know to find the position is calling the function InStr inside my function InStr. For each comma I wanna ignore, I need to call another InStr inside the others, and that's some advance loop I can't think of.

Comment: Or Split each line on the commas to form an array which you can then iterate over to write to the cells in turn... You can also choose not to write some elements into the various cells as you please.  `myArray = Split(Cells(i,1), ",")` will give you muich better control over the elements you want to use

Comment: I want to have a table (starts on the cell B1 and goes down and right) with the values that are on the column A (after I get my table full, I will delete the column A and the VBA code).

Comment: Split may be the answer, it's just that I can't find the solution because I have to think of so much stuff to make it right. It's a big data.

Comment: If it is only one time exercise as mentioned in your comment why not use Excel native functions. To me simplest way if your data structure is consistent, is to save as a csv file and then import in Excel with delimiters like ',' '(" . It will split the values into various columns. Then this can be easily adjusted to suit to your requirements. Excel-VBA may be an overkill for such casual applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Split()` instead:

If you want to put all the values in the same order that they already appear in:

```
Dim values As Variant

For i = 2 to Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    values = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ",")
    Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, UBound(values) + 1).Value = values

Next
```

Or if you want different values in different columns:

```
Dim values As Variant

For i = 2 to Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    '// Create an array of values from your string
    values = Split(Cells(i, 1).Value, ",")

    '// Lets say you want to put the 3rd value in column D
    Range("D" & i).Value = CStr(values(2)) '// arrays are zero indexed and start at 0

Next
```

---

Comment: I get an error on the loop. Probably Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)

Comment: You're updated first code works perfectly I think. I'm not sure what's the second for but I think I just need a loop to make the first one for around 126 columns.

Comment: @VBAAdvance the first one should do then, it just splits all the values out on each comma and re-writes the values to each cell. Don't forget to accept as the answer if it helped (green tick on the left)

Comment: Can you help me with the j loop to make it on all the columns? What's the value on you're code to change to j? If not, I think I can figure it out with some time.

Comment: @VBAAdvance If you use the top example in my code (check again because I've edited it) you don't need the `j` loop - run it and see. **(always make a backup of your workbook before running VBA code - there is no 'undo' option!)**